# CSS - div 100% width of page not parent - div after and before

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask for a help with this task:
I need to force div to have 100% width of page, NOT parent.
This is possible in way like this:

```
<style>
   .parent {width:980px; margin:0 auto;}
   .maxwidth {position: absolute; left: 0; right:0; width:100%; height: auto;}
</style>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="before">
      height is not fixed
   </div>

   <div class="maxwidth">
      100% width of page
   </div>

    <div class="after">
       height is not fixed
    </div>
</div>
```

But i don't now how to make DIVs .before and .after work with not-fixed height. 
Problem is, that DIV .after is not visible because it is under div .maxwidth and when I make DIV .before higher (for example put more text inside), it is again under div .maxwidth.

Thank You for help.

Comment: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0; bottom: 0, you won't need width: 100%, height: 100%

Comment: please note that the parents of the div can't have `position:relative` or `absolute`

Comment: Can you modify the HTML and create two parent divs for before and after; leaving maxwidth outside of a parent wrapper? [Like this example](http://jsbin.com/pujego/1/edit)? Or can you not change the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

setting `.maxwidth` to `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` will make it full screen

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L89y98n6/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this in this way:

```
<style>
   .parent {width:980px; margin:0 auto;}
   .maxwidth {position: absolute; left: 0; right:0; width:100%; height:60px;}
   .before {height: auto;}
   .after {height:auto; margin-top:60px;}
</style>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="before">
      height is not fixed
   </div>

   <div class="maxwidth">
      100% width of page
   </div>

    <div class="after">
       height is not fixed
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it allright or is there space for some problems?